# Chrome and Firefox not scaling correctly on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, plasma-5

I know this question has been asked many times but I've tried everything suggested but still the pages that load on chrome look horribly small on kubuntu Can anyone please suggest me a solution? Here's a list of things that I've tried - 
1.) Forcing font dpi. (doesn't work at all)
2.) Editing google-chrome.desktop file `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=1.2` (for me setting the scale-factor = 1.2) works best in fixing the scale of the UI. But still unlike a windows machine where every page loads and looks correct, in Kubuntu 60% of pages are still loading with a very small font size.
P.S - I've also tried changing font size from chrome's settings but it's also ineffective.

Comment: Is it the text? Both browsers have a way to set a minimum font size. Would that work for you?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes! I've tried that too but still on some pages not just the text but the whole content looks tiny